# log4j2 is giving: java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries

Tags: java, spring-boot, hadoop, log4j2

I have a spring boot web application that is working perfectly fine with below gradle dependecies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }   
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    implementation 'org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap'
    implementation 'org.springframework:spring-tx'
    implementation 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk'

    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9'
    implementation 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3.0'
    implementation('org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:1.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate'
    }

    implementation("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.1") {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'
    }

    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5:3.0.4.RELEASE'

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use `log4j2` for logging, so I added to the dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
```

But once I do that, the following error starts to show:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:356) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:371) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:364) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:272) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:311) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:?]
    at com.fpl.postal.gui.hive.HiveDataSource.getHiveDataSource(HiveDataSource.java:45) ~[main/:?]
    at com.fpl.postal.gui.hive.HiveDataSource.getJDBCTemplate(HiveDataSource.java:57) ~[main/:?]
    at com.fpl.postal.gui.hive.HiveDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62d001ae.CGLIB$getJDBCTemplate$1(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at com.fpl.postal.gui.hive.HiveDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62d001ae$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cffdbdd0.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.fpl.postal.gui.hive.HiveDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$62d001ae.getJDBCTemplate(<generated>) ~[main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) [spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) [spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.fpl.postal.gui.PostalGuiApplication.main(PostalGuiApplication.java:14) [main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
```

I think is like a dependency conflict. Any idea on how to fix this? Please keep in mind this error only happens when I add `log4j2` library.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Log4j` Gradle dependency.

**Gradle dependency :**

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.13.2'
  compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.13.2'
}
```

reference : [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html)

Comment: I think for spring boot application it is just needed: `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2'`